# Entity Framework with a Large Project

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Me and my team are going to start a new Project and we are at the stage of exploring and testing some new (or not so new) technologies.

Till today we were using classic ADO with DBDataReaders, proxies for lazy loading and in some cases DataTables.

The team consists of 3 developers and one Database designer.
Our projects consists at least 130 tables each.

Our new project has the potential to grow so we expect 100 tables for sure.

I have been reading and doing some simple testing with EF5 the last 2 days and i still can't decide if we should use it.

1. We usually split a big Project into many "module" projects allowing us to work faster and better under source control. Are we going to use one big "edmx" for the whole DB?
2. Since we have a Database Designer i suspect that CodeFirst is not an option.. So is it worth to use EF with the Database First approach?
3. If we use the Database first approach is the EF smart enough to detect all the relationships correctly and be ready for usage with no more additional configuration by me? (By extra configurations i mean i will have to write DataAnnotations or have to ovveride the DbContext)
4. Personally i find my self very confident about designing a Database with sql. The only annoyance i have is when i have to update all of the select, delete, update, insert scripts when an entity is changed in my classes-Lists.
   EF will take care this for me but except this i'm starting to believe that it will slow down the performance and eventually slow down my production since we are not familiar with it..

What do you think IS IT WORTH IT ?

*Except the DataAnnotations and the DbContext ovveride, is anyone using plain T4 templates to create the tables(schema)?

Comment: You are asking a lot of questions regarding Entity Framework - too many for the type of question-answer format described in the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Please limit the scope of the question and if necessary create multiple questions.

Entity Framework is an excellent technology and, in my opinion, the efforts to learn the framework are a benefit regardless of your team's decision.

Comment: Thanks for your time Abstract,
I was trying to present my current situation (dilemma) as good and fast as possible.
I don't expect in depth analysis on each of my questions.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? VS2012 allows you to use multiple diagrams for the same .edmx.

Comment: Just my experience. do not use EF in a large project.there are many bugs in it.and you may spend many time to fight with them. just a google about: EF bugs!

Comment: I would strongly suggest you take a look at EF 5 using the Fluent API. You can still go 'DB First' but with more of a seperation between the code and the DB - no model/diagram needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided not to use the EF.
I am not going to take the risk of using it in a big project.

All the work needed to use it, the possibility of dealing with bugs, the extra overhead..
I prefer writing more sql code and spend more time maintaining, than dealing with the generated models or checking the sql profiler for the generated queries..

Thank you all for your comments..

*Before i go to straight ADO again i will give a shot to FluentData and Dapper..
I will open a new question so if you guys wanna comment on these two light ORMs, i will post the link later.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you still take a look at EF 5 using the Fluent API. You can still go 'DB First' but with more of a seperation between the code and the DB - no model/diagram needed. A couple of links to see how to solve common tasks using the Fluent API - 
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)
and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620)

Comment: At my company we extensively use SQL Server Data Tools projects to manage various databases. On the application side, we have EF DB first. It works quite well and migrations aren't terrible either via SSDT.

Comment: Have you ever tried NHibernate? I thing about Entity Framework like you. Entity Framework infrastructure is very complex and not flexible. But NHibernate uses XML.

Answer (score 4):

1. I'd absolutely recommend to create multiple models. You can select which tables, views, and stored procedures to map for each.
2. Database first is absolutely fine.
3. If the database constraints have been set then EF will recognize them. You won't get around minor modifications, but all in all EF does a pretty good job.
4. Using EF will have a slight impact on query performance. But in most cases that won't be an issue. In the few cases where you may have an unacceptable performance hit, you can optimize by injecting your own SQL into EF where necessary.

I think, you'll become familiar with the usage of EF pretty quickly, therefore I don't think unfamiliarity will be an issue for long.

Comment: #2 is true but with certain caveats to customization of models or POCOs.

Comment: @IAbstract yes, but that might not be that big of an issue given that the alternative seems to be working with ADO.NET and proxies for lazy loading in OP's case.

Comment: I'd like to add that you can get both in-code mapping (code-first is a silly name for code mappings alone, IMO) and database-first approach. Just use 'EF Power Tools' VS-add on and use 'Reverse engineer code-first' option to create the code mappings from existing database.

Comment: Dennis thanks for your time,
I was thinking of creating multiple models too but i ended up in a scenario where i had some tables multiple times on multiple models..
I don't know if this is the expected behavior or i have done something in my design horribly wrong.

Comment: @SteliosKornelakis I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Having some tables in multiple models doesn't really matter that much (I'd expect this to be the case in a rather complex scenario). But I recommend having each module with the respective edmx-model in its own project. EF sometimes gets confused when using multiple models with the same class names in one project, no matter if you use different namespaces or not.

Comment: Yes but changing a table in one edmx will not reflect the changes to others requiring me to do the same task n times..:(

Comment: @SteliosKornelakis that's true but might be a benefit. You could accustom the different models to the respective needs without having to change the database schema.

Answer (score -1):

If your database structure is mature, EF should be a good solution for you.

If the database structure is being developed, or will change alot over time, I would assert that EF may not be the best for you.

EF needs to be refreshed when there are structural changes (and potentially interface changes at the database layer).  You should consider how you will manage database changes within your already developed code base.

Comment: -1 So if you are not using EF and you changed the DB structure you won't need to change anything?

Comment: I was answering the question and trying to be helpful.  You seem to have an answer, perhaps you should submit it.

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but I am 100% sure about the point you mentioned,, it wasn't helpful.

Comment: I'd make the reverse argument. If you are developing your DB, then EF is a god send as it can help you with DB migrations. Once you have a mature database, if you find areas that need added performance, you might consider writing naked SQL or Stored Procedures, and even using a Micro-ORM like Dapper on specific, performance-critical parts.